# Rgbdslam how to build

Tags: rosmake, ros-package-path, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm very new to ros and have been trying to rosmake rgbdslam. I added the two svn sources from the wiki and am not sure how to add them into ros so that it will build. Is there something implied in the wiki that needs to be done to add rgbdslam to rosmake. Is rosinstall used to make proper setup? Please help, thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9750/rgbdslam-how-to-build/) by [Jason3d](https://answers.ros.org/users/433/jason3d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you added the two directories you downloaded to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in your .bashrc file? (i.e. if you have both directories in folder ~/rgbd, then add ~/rgbd). If you don't know how to do this, add this line to your .bashrc file:

> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=DIR:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Replace "DIR" with the directory your folders are located at, i.e. ~/rgbd.

If you've correctly done so, running the command "rosmake rgbdslam" should build the entire solution for you. If you haven't done so, you'll likely get some error that says rosmake cannot find package rgbdslam.

Shark

---

Originally posted by [Shark](https://answers.ros.org/users/264/shark/) with karma: 241 on 2011-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thankyou for responding so quickly, that worked instantly. I kept adding the path under opt/ros/diamondback/setup.sh but it didn't work. Editing .bashrc worked.

---

Originally posted by [Jason3d](https://answers.ros.org/users/433/jason3d/) with karma: 11 on 2011-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-04-16**:
With ROS, you shouldn't need edit anything under /opt/ros/..., in general you can do all required edits somewhere within your home directory.